# Import excel data and store it in database using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my index file

```
<form action="DataImport" method="post>"

    <input name="filename" type="file" size="20">

    <input type="submit" value="Import">
```

DataImport.java(Servlet)

```
public class DataImport extends HttpServlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DataImport()
    {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        try
        {
            String file = request.getParameter("file");

            String fileName1=""+file+"";

            ArrayList dataHolder = read.readExcelFile(fileName1);

            Connection con = EmployeeDao1.con11();
            System.out.println("Connection :"+con);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Statement sql_statement = con.createStatement();
            String jdbc_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO emp4"
                    + "(Id,name,salary) VALUES"
                    + "(?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(jdbc_insert_sql);
            int count=0;

            ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=null;
            for(int i=1;i<dataHolder.size();i++)
            {
                cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
                ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
                ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
                ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
                count= ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            if(count>0)
            {
                for (int j=1;j < dataHolder.size(); j++)
                {
                    cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(j);
                    System.out.println(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
                    System.out.println(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
                    System.out.println(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

this my read.java class to read the excel file

```
public class read {
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})

    public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName) {

        ArrayList cellArrayLisstHolder = new ArrayList();
        try {
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("D:\\LOGA\\Book1.xlsx"));
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();

                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                ArrayList cellStoreArrayList = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    cellStoreArrayList.add(cell);
                    int cellType = cell.getCellType();
                    if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        HSSFRichTextString strData = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("String data=" + strData.getString());
                    } else if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        double data = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Numeric data=" + data);
                    }
                }
                cellArrayLisstHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cellArrayLisstHolder;
    }
}
```

when i try to execute the servlet it shows the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet DataImport threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at pack.DataImport.doPost(DataImport.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)




    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can any one solve this problem?
and i have included all my poi and sql jar files, also excel file(Book1.xslx) is in `D:\\LOGA` only...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've forgotten to include the POI library on the CLASSPATH (e.g. It's not referenced by your web app). You can include this lib under WEB-INF/lib (in your WAR archive or in the exploded directory format) or it can sit elsewhere in your app server/web server CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="DataImport" method="post>"
```

There is small mistake here

the quotes are out of form tag

```
method="post>"
```

just change it

```
<form action="DataImport" method="post">
```

and also change the servlet entry this

```
String file = request.getParameter("file");
```

to this

```
String file = request.getParameter("filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution ....working fine
file upload.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="excel"  class="com.ImportExcel"/>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.jsp" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filename">
<input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.Date" %>  
    <%@ page import ="java.io.*" %>  
    <%@ page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>  
    <%@ page import ="java.io.IOException" %>  
    <%@ page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>  
    <%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
    <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>  
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>  
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>  
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>  
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook" %>
    <%@ page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%

    ArrayList cellArrayListHolder = new ArrayList (); 

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");  
        String Path="upload";
        String absolutepath=getServletContext().getRealPath(Path);
        MultipartRequest   mr=new MultipartRequest(request,absolutepath);
        String filename=mr.getOriginalFileName("filename");
        FileInputStream myinput = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutepath+"/"+filename));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(myinput);
        /*Create a workbook using myfilesystem  */
        /* Get the first sheet from workbook */
         Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        /*We need to something to iterate through the cell  */
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            XSSFRow nextRow =(XSSFRow)iterator.next();
            ArrayList rowarrylist=new ArrayList();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

             while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                 XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell)cellIterator.next();
                 rowarrylist.add(cell);    
             }    
             cellArrayListHolder.add(rowarrylist);
        }
        out.println(cellArrayListHolder);
        ArrayList rowarrylist=null;
        PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  export VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        for(int i=1;i<cellArrayListHolder.size();i++)
        {  
                rowarrylist=(ArrayList)cellArrayListHolder.get(i);
                st.setString(1,rowarrylist.get(0)

.toString());
            st.setString(2,rowarrylist.get(1).toString());
            st.setString(3,rowarrylist.get(2).toString());
            st.setString(4,rowarrylist.get(3).toString());
            st.executeUpdate(); 
            } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage();
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```